# Run GSAP animation after window.onload

Tags: javascript, onload, gsap, preload, preloader

Im using the window.onload as a preloader like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
document.querySelector(".preloader").style.display = "none";
}
```

And it works fine. The problem is, that i also use GSAP for a intro animation, and if the load takes to much time, the animation will run underneath the .preloader element.

So my question is, how do i tricker the gsap animation part, only after the whole page is loaded?

For reference, this is my animation:

```
    gsap.timeline()
    .from("#parallax-bg-1", {opacity:0, scale:1.1, duration:1.0, ease:Power1.easeInOut}, "+=0.0")
    .from(".hero span", {y:'80%', stagger:0.2, duration:2.0, ease:Expo.easeInOut}, "-=1.0")
```

Comment: You'd trigger as usual, just place that code in the `onload` function, along with whatever's already in there.

Comment: We at GreenSock recommend that you use yPercent and the condensed string form for eases instead of what you have. See [the most common GSAP mistakes](https://greensock.com/mistakes/) for more info.